# How to center text inside background image?

Tags: html, css

This piece of text isn't centering properly in the div. Any help would be great! Here is the CSS desk file http://www.cssdesk.com/Vc8yF As you can see the text is more to the left than center. Please help! Thank you.

**Code Snippet:**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.header {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #191919;
}
.navcontainer {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 100px;
}
.nav li {
  display: inline;
  font-family: arial;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
.billboard {
  height: 620px;
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url('http://i300.photobucket.com/albums/nn18/ojijimanuel/Midtown_Manhattan_and_Times_Square_district_2015_zpsqimz80ub.jpg');
}
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="header">
    <div class="navcontainer">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="billboard">
    <h1>SAMPLE TEXT</h1>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to center the text both vertically and horizontally?

Comment: Yes I am trying to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assumed you wanted to center the text both vertically and horizontally:

View the [result here](http://www.cssdesk.com/QjAD9)

I created a new cssDesk with the fixes. To sum up, I added a `position: relative` to the billboard div and then added a wrapper div with `position:absolute` with a little trick to center the text inside it.

**Code Snippet:**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.header {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #191919;
}
.navcontainer {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 100px;
}
.nav li {
  display: inline;
  font-family: arial;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
.billboard {
  height: 620px;
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url('http://i300.photobucket.com/albums/nn18/ojijimanuel/Midtown_Manhattan_and_Times_Square_district_2015_zpsqimz80ub.jpg');
  position: relative;
}
.text-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: -200px;
  margin-top: -29px;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="header">
    <div class="navcontainer">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="billboard">
    <div class="text-wrapper">
      <h1>SAMPLE TEXT</h1>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: My pleasure! Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

This is a very weird behaviour, but as always with floats.

This come from the fact that your nav is too big for its container so the float sort of "spreads out" of it.

You can add clear:right; on you h1 or height:50px; on your .navcontainer, it will make the deal

Answer (score 0):

This is being caused by the float of the navigation. The navigation is higher than it's wrapper, forcing the element bellow (billboard) to shrink.
There are various ways to solve this problem, pick one of the following:

- Adjusting the margins on the `<ul>` of the navigation, so it fits inside the header
- Adding overflow: hidden to the header
- Adding clear: right/both to the billboard